# Azure Functions: Maximum number of instances on consumption plan

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless, azure-functions-runtime

According to Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale), a `Function` app can scale to 200 instances on consumption plan. Is this a technical limit or a safety limit to curb abuse? I know that sometimes Azure Support can increase limits on demand. I'm designing a backend system with high scalability in mind. I'm trying to decide if I should create multiple `Function` apps to get around this limitation.

How can one scale their backend server beyond 200 instances while staying on consumption plan to meet demand?

Answer (score 4):

> Is this a technical limit or a safety limit to curb abuse?

At present, we can only learn from official documents or actual operations that the maximum can be scaled to 200 instances. If you want to scale more instances, or wonder why there is such a limit, I am afraid you can only ask for help from Azure official support.

[image]

> How can one scale their backend server beyond 200 instances while staying on consumption plan to meet demand?

I'm afraid you can only create multiple Functions to achieve your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if thats a hard or soft limit - you can always just open a support ticket to find out ;-) But even if it's a soft limit, they will usually come back and question why you really need this.

However, if you expect scale to 200 (and more...) instances, you app sounds like something fairly heavy and potentially critical. In such as scenario I would - for multiple reasons - consider deployed your app to multiple regions. Assuming they are HTTP-triggered functions, put an Azure Front Door in front for load balancing.

Comment: Or an Azure Traffic Manager?